# How can I access only specific input fields using foreach loop in Laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am a newbie here and using livewire, I'm doing multiple submissions such that user can add many topics and their respective fields. Here is my form:

```
@foreach ($topics as $index => $topic )
                <div class="form-column new-form">
                    <h1 class="form-title">Topics </h1>
                    <div class="form-column">
                        <label for="topicname">topic name</label>
                        <input type="url" name="topics[{{$index}}][name]" wire:model="topics.{{$index}}.name" id="topicname" placeholder="Enter topic name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-column">
                            <label for="coursestatus">status</label>
                            <select name="topics[{{$index}}][status]" id="status" wire:model="topics.{{$index}}.status">
                                <option value="enabled" selected>Enabled</option>
                                <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-column">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-column">
                        <label for="topicdescription">topic description</label>
                        <textarea name="topics[{{$index}}][description]" wire:model="topics.{{$index}}.description" id="topicdescription" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-column">
                        <label for="topicdocuments">any documents?</label>
                        <input type="file" name="topics[{{$index}}][document]" wire:model="topics.{{$index}}.document" multiple>
                    </div>
                    <button class="form-submit" wire:click.prevent="removetopic({{ $index }})">Remove topic&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></button>


                </div>
                @endforeach
                <div class="form-row">
                    <button class="form-submit" wire:click.prevent="back">Course&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i></button>
                    <button type="submit" class="form-reset"><i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reset</button>
                    <button type="submit" wire:click.prevent="addtopic" class="form-submit"><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add This Topic</button>
                    <button class="form-submit" wire:click.prevent="test">Lessons&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></button>
                </div>
```

I can fetch full array of the form using test function in my livewire component:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire; 
use Livewire\Component; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; 

class Courseupload extends Component
{

public $topics = []

public function mount()
{
    $this->topics = [[
        'name'=>'', 'descrption'=> '', 'status'=> '', 'document'=> ''
    ]];
}


public function addtopic()  
{
    $this->topics[] = ['name'=> '', 'status'=> '', 'description'=>'', 'document'=>''];

}

public function test()
{
   dd($this->topics); 
}
}
```

Example array
[Array of multiple forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTQ6h.png)

How can I fetch only specific fields like 'name', 'description' etc. from every form generated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your `array` to a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) and then use the [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) method to get the single field you want. If you want multiple fields then you can [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map) over each of the elements and use the [`Arr::only`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-only) method to return the fields you want.

For example:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'First nane', 'status' => 'First status', 'description' => 'First description', 'document' => 'First document'],
    ['name' => 'Second name', 'status' => 'Second status', 'description' => 'Second description', 'document' => 'Second document']
]);

$singleField = $collection->pluck('name');

$multipleFields = $collection->map(function ($iter) {
    return Arr::only($iter, ['name', 'status']);
});

dd($singleField, $multipleFields);
```

How the above would differ for you, is you would be using your `$this->topics` property directly:

```
$collection = collect($this->topics);
```